# Do we have a canonical question documenting all the /execute subcommands?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

As you may or may not know, `/execute` in MCBE has been updated, and its syntax has been changed to have parity with Java Edition.

I plan to release a self-answered question detailing the updates to `/execute`'s syntax on MCBE. It will go over the differences that remain between it and Java's `/execute`. However, this cannot be done if there isn't info detailing Java's `/execute` in the first place.

I've been searching for a canonical question that details each `/execute` subcommand as it stands in Java Edition, because I could have sworn there was one. Alas, the closest I could find is our general [basics question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354615/250180) and [this ol' question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370684/250180) which I dug up from a while ago, but no one cared about because it was too specific.

Considering as many commands users find the Minecraft Wiki confusing, a post that goes into detail with phrasing optimized for beginners would be a great thing to have. Would it be best to:

- turn that second question into the canonical (my preference),
- make a new question,
- use an existing question that I failed to find in my search,
- not do it at all, and why?

**P.S.** That [partial rewrite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/354615/12) I made to the basics post quite a while ago? I think I might have enough free time to revise the other half, too! We'll see…

Comment: Can't you just edit the wiki to be less confusing? It's way more likely that people contribute to that. And documenting an entire feature is exactly what it's for.

Comment: @FabianRöling The nature of wiki documentation just makes it not well-suited for beginners. The wiki's job is to document the technical nature of different features, which means it includes the small technical details with the basic info. Most beginners reading the wiki page will be overwhelmed with the information they receive. And it's not like the info can be removed or moved, as the wiki *needs* that information for power-users who rely on it. I just don't believe in using the wiki to give a primer on a subject for beginners, and I think a site like this would be the perfect place.

Comment: I don't see any downside if you release a self-answered question for our site, so yes please

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I'll take it on if and when time permits, just wanted to make sure that it would be okay